# failed to parse timestamp elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and am trying to create my first index but am having issues with a timestamp field that was working before...

I created my index like this:

```
PUT /kafkasdp
{
  "mappings": {
    "kafka_logs": {
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "log_level": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "message1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "message2": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

and then I'm trying to send data like this:

```
post /kafkasdp/kafka_logs
{
  "timestamp": "2017-02-03 19:27:20,606",
  "log_level": "INFO",
  "message2": "Deleting segment 1 from log omega-replica-sync-dev-8. (kafka.log.Log)"
}
```

but keep getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse [timestamp]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse [timestamp]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Invalid format: \"2017-02-03 19:27:20,606\" is malformed at \" 19:27:20,606\""
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I thought my timestamp is a valid date type?

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: here's what I got back...`  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.2.0",
    "build_hash" : "24e05b9",
    "build_date" : "2017-01-24T19:52:35.800Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.0"
  },`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read about date type on [Elasticsearch reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/date.html): you should specify format of date you are expecting in your documents:

```
PUT your_index_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_index_type": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you did not specify it, Elasticsearch will expect date value in ISO format:
`yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'` (e.g., `2017-02-03T19:27:20.606Z`)

Comment: I'm confused...i thought it accepts any of these formats?: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/mapping-date-format.html#strict-date-time...maybe I'm not understanding this but shouldn't it work via the 'date_hour_minute_second_fraction'

Comment: @user2061886, `date_hour_minute_second_fraction` accepts `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`. As specified in that article you provided, it is built-in format and all built-in formats are ISO