# How do I parse timestamps correctly when using saveToEs to save data from a Spark DataFrame to Elasticsearch?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

In my DataFrame I have timestamps (stored as strings) in the following formats:

| timestamp_format_A | timestamp_format_B |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-03 11.25.19 | 2021-03-03 11:25:19 |

Both of these fields are interpreted and stored as "text" when I push this data to Elasticsearch via

```
myDataFrame.saveToEs("my-index/_doc")
```

I am using Elasticsearch as the back-end for a single-page web app, and need to provide the functionality of querying these fields as dates for our end-users. When the fields are stored as "text", users are unable to send query strings like

```
timestamp_format_A:>2018
```

So far, I've tried applying date mappings to my index **before** I push the data to Elasticsearch as outlined in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) as follows

```
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp_format_A": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss"
      },
      "timestamp_format_B": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I do that I get an error saying the following upon pushing the data:

```
illegal_argument_exception: mapper [timestamp_format_A] cannot be changed from type [date] to [text]
```

This is a bit confusing because I would have thought that it would be trying to do the reverse.

The above solution is recommended in the below posts:

- [failed to parse timestamp elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043856/failed-to-parse-timestamp-elasticsearch)
- [ElasticSearch indexing issue ,failed to parse timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626578/elasticsearch-indexing-issue-failed-to-parse-timestamp)

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong here... how do I get the timestamps to parse correctly as date types?

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I decided to make my data work for Elasticsearch, rather than trying to make Elasticsearch work for my data.

In my pre-processing pipeline, I transformed the timestamp fields into the ISO 8601 format that Elasticsearch expects by default:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{to_timestamp, date_format}

myDataFrame = myDataFrame.withColumn("timestamp_format_A", date_format(to_timestamp(col("timestamp_format_A"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
myDataFrame = myDataFrame.withColumn("timestamp_format_B", date_format(to_timestamp(col("timestamp_format_B"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
```

The fields are now parsed and stored correctly as dates, but I am still open to alternative solutions that don't require changes to the format of the source data.